# How to check and prompt the user of the missing field using appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a request form using google sheet and send it to the designated person using appscript. Now, before sending the request form a validation must be done to check for the missing inputs.

For example here, user will select an item in the description column, then stock number and unit column will automatically have values upon selecting an item. For each item selected in the description column, user must input the quantity before sending the request form. So if the user clicked on the "RIS" tab and there is a missing field, it will prompt the user that there is a missing field.
 [image: Request Form]

This is currently what I have coded, this is to convert the sheet into a pdf and send it to the designated person.

```
function showAlert() {
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('RIS Form');

  //var division = sh.getRange('B6').getValue().toString();
  //var pname = sh.getRange('C50').getValue().toString();

  try{
    var result = ui.prompt(
      'Submit request?',
      'Enter recipient's email address:',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

    var button = result.getSelectedButton();
    var email = result.getResponseText();

    var message = {
      to: (email),
      subject: "Request and Issuance Slip",
      body: "New request! Please see attached file.",
      name: "RIS Alert",
      //replyTo: "",
      //cc: (),
      attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Request Form")]
    }

    // Process the user's response.
    if (button == ui.Button.YES){
      // User clicked "Yes"
      transfer (); //function to transfer stock number, unit, description and quantity to DB Sheet
      hideAllSheetsExcept('RIS Form'); //function
      MailApp.sendEmail(message);
      ui.alert("Your request has been sent");
    }
      
    else{
      //User clicked "No"
      ui.Button.CLOSE;
    }
  } catch(e){
    ui.alert(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: How about using google sheets formula and/or conditional formatting instead which will say in the cell that an input is required and highlight the cell red if it is blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### USING FORMULA:

While I was suggesting google sheets formula like this in `conditional formatting`,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(NOT(ISBLANK(C11:C40))*(ISBLANK(D11:D40)))
```

**RESULT:**
[image]

---

#### USING APPS SCRIPT

**Here is also a suggestion/ alternative solution using AppsScript**:

```
function toCheckMissingFields() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("C11:D40"); // necessary range for checking 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C11:C40").getValues().flat().filter(item=>item);
   // console.log(dataRange)
 
  for (var row = 1; row <= dataRange.length; row++) {
  //console.log(row)
  var cRow = range.getCell(row,1) //get column C with its row
  var dRow = range.getCell(row,2) //get column D with its row
  //console.log(row)
      if ((!cRow.isBlank()) && dRow.isBlank() )  {
        var cellAddress = dRow.getA1Notation();
        console.log(cellAddress)
        var message = "Missing field at " + cellAddress + ". Please fill in the missing field.";
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(message);
        return; // Stop checking if a missing field is found
      
    }
  }
  
  // If no missing fields are found
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("All fields are filled.");
}
```

- This will check the missing fields for `column D`, if there's a selected value from the dropdown list in `column C`.
- *Please be careful not to skip any row as it will affect the output.*

**RESULT:**
[image]